# WD NAS vs hd sentinel on disk health

Tags: hard-drive, nas, smart, hard-drive-failure

My Western Digital My Book Live II, started failing some time ago, with a "Drive A Failed" message on the Web Interface monitor tool.
After replacing Drive A, with a new one, drive B failed also a couple of months later. So i replaced drive B also.

So now that i found some time to look at the disks, and after i formated them both, i ran some tests using HD Sentinel. Surprisingly, both of the disks had 100% health, no bad sectors, or any other read/write problems.

So, could i trust HD Sentinel, which of course means trusting S.M.A.R.T. also, or should i trust the NAS?
Do you think i should use those disks? Or just toss them away...?

Thank you!

Comment: Exactly which disks did you run tests on? The ones that failed and were replaced, or their replacements? What sort of tests did you run? Is your data worth anything to you? Do you have additional backups or would the potentially-bad drives hold an only copy of the data? Etc.

Comment: I tested the failed ones. I ran the "extended" test (not sure of the name of it, not sitting in my PC at the moment). I am thinking of making a RAID 1 of them in my home-PC to hold data, that won't be backed up anywhre else. So the question is should i count on mirroring, plus the hd sentinel tests?